# How to combine Component.getServerSideProps props and MyApp.getInitialState props?

Tags: next.js

Next.js has an App component. There is an App component in Next.js where I can change props for each component when it rendering:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  // Here some actions with pageProps
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

But if i want to use MyApp.getInitialProps:

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps }
}
```

Then in browser after console.log(props) i see only props, that i have with function Component.getServerSideProps.

But how can I combine in component props the props received via MyApp.getInitialProps and the props received via Component.getServerSideProps ?

P.S. It is not essential for me to use MyApp.getInitialState. GetServerSideProps will do too, the main thing is to combine the props

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combine? The props returned by `getServerSideProps` will already be combined with the props returned by `getInitialProps`. Props with the same name in both will have the value returned by `getServerSideProps`, as it overrides `getInitialProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves yea thx. Before your comment i did something wrong. Now in MyApp.getInitialProps i return { pageProps: { text: '13' }  } and all right, i have both props. Thx